# Cómo puedo graficar un conjunto de tendencias en R?

Tags: r

Buen día, estoy tratando de graficar varias graficas por cada año en R, algo asi: 
 [image: Grafica 1]

Quisiera en vez de esto, hacerlo con las tendencias, es decir, que cada grafico, sea una tendencia de ese año, esta tendencia es del año 2000 
[image: Tendencia del mes de enero del año 2000]

Para el primer grafico use un barplot con una tabla en excel y para la segunda grafica use un ggplot. Agradeceria una ayuda para este fin, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Valeria, así como está tu pregunta podría ser considerada como demasiado amplia y eventualmente terminar cerrada, ¿podrías agregar el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora y un ejemplo de los datos que estás graficando? Saludos

Comment: Hola Valeria, bienvenida. Con toda seguridad vas a tener una respuesta si agregás un ejemplo mínimo de los datos con los que estás trabajando y un ejemplo del código con el que estás intentando resolver tu problema o te lleva al menos a un resultado intermedio. Una buena alternativa es pegar la salida en consola: de esta línea:  `dput(head(datos))`, donde `datos` son los datos importados a R con los que estás trabajando. Podés editar tu pregunta, buscá el enlace `Editar` cuando la visualices. Saludos y bienvenida nuevamente.